# The audio is not played correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I have a loop where I want to play a sound for each loop. However, what I get is the first sound and then a pause and after that I get the correct sounds after each other without the long pause.

The code:

```
async Task PopCards() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Utility.buttons_List.Count; i++) 
    {
        audioData.Play(0);
        Utility.buttons_List[i].transform.DOShakeScale(0.05f, 0.4f, 2, 80f, true, ShakeRandomnessMode.Harmonic);  
        Utility.buttons_List[i].transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

I also use DoTween.